# Spring Session Redis: How to reduce the 'exists xxx' requests to redis server

Tags: spring, redis, spring-session

I'm now using spring-session-redis to manage user sessions (a spring-boot project).

The spring-session framework checks the expiration of keys every minute and runs `exists` command before deleting expired keys.

The framework uses a internal scheduler (not a distributed scheduler) for each running node. Thus, each node runs the same commands every minute.

Now I have nearly 100 nodes for a single service, and there are quite a lot `exists` commands sent to the redis server. But most of them are redundant. (Because the 100 nodes are running the same commands, at the same time)

The `exists` commands cost a lot of CPU resource, and I'm wondering how to reduce the redundant `exists` commands.